# different datatypes

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I try to add different datatypes to an array:

```
mtype = np.dtype({'names':['a', 's', 'x', 'y'], 
                  'formats':['f8', 'S10', 'f8',   'f8']})
```

or

```
mtype = np.dtype([("a", np.float), ("s", np.str), 
                  ("x", np.float), ("y", np.float)])
```

array:

```
a[i] = np.empty([4, d[i]], dtype= mtype)
```

The data to array `a` is read from SQL queries, there are 4 different arrays `a` in a loop:

```
a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]
```

and for each different there is different SQL query.

The data in database is read by sqlite3 package:

```
cur.execute(('''CREATE TABLE example
     (a real, s text , t real, x real, y real)''')

for j in range(len(rows)):
     a[i][0, j] = rows[j][0]
     a[i][1, j] = rows[j][1]
     a[i][2, j] = rows[j][2]
     a[i][3, j] = rows[j][3]
```

And then I get the error:

```
File "C:\(..)", line 39,
in diff_spec
     a[i][0, j] = rows[j][0]
TypeError: expected a readable buffer object
```

If I make just the array `a` as:

```
a[i] = np.empty([4, d[i]], float)
```

and I don't read second column (which is string), I will not get the error.

```
for j in range(len(rows)):
    a[i][0, j] = rows[j][0]
    # a[i][1, j] = rows[j][1]
    a[i][2, j] = rows[j][2]
    a[i][3, j] = rows[j][3]
```

Can anybody explain why does this happen? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please confirm, is `np` an alias for `numpy`?

Comment: ah, I am sorry, yes, sure, it's numpy

Comment: one more, it works when I create **a** array, like:
`a[i] = np.empty([4, d[i]], dtype=np.object)`
but then I can't use ex. `log10` on a column of **a**